# npm doesn't uninstall packages

Tags: npm, package

I've been trying to remove some packages that I installed with npm but it doesn't remove them. After running `npm uninstall -g package` the package is still executable in my terminal and it is still in the path where npm binaries are being installed.

Also, why is npm installing packages in `~/.local/share/npm/bin/` ? It's the first time that I've seem npm installing packages there. I had a problem a few weeks ago when installing some language servers but they weren't executable, turns out I had to add `~/.local/share/npm/bin` to my `$PATH` because that's where npm was installing everything. And now npm doesn't remove any package installed there. I've already look into the npm config (npmrc) but I don't see any option changing the install path. The only environment variable related to npm that I have is to set the user config in `~/.config/npm` instead of `~/.npmrc`.

I have others machines with the exact same settings and npm it's not installing packages in `~/.local/share/npm/bin/` and I'm able to uninstall packages normally.

Does anyone knows whats wrong with npm ?

`npm --version 7.8.0`

my config:

```
cache=/home/user/.cache/npm
init-module=/home/user/.config/npm/config/npm-init.js
package-lock=false
tmp=/run/user/1000/npm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I noticed that if I reinstalled the packages that I couldn't remove they went into a different folder /user/bin/ with the node_modules being in /user/lib/node_modules. Before it was in ~/.local/share/npm/lib. Now with the packages were they belong I can't remove them without issues. No idea why those packages were originally installed in a different path.